# JavaFX unable to display rectangle inside grid

Tags: javafx

So my teacher has just started teaching us how to use JavaFx and up until now, I had thought I had a pretty good grasp of the material. But, I am stuck and I don't quite know how to fix the issue or even what's causing the issue. I am trying to create a green rectangle that is three nodes high on a grid that is 64x64. The grid shows up just fine but for the life of me, I cannot understand why the rectangle is not showing up as well. Can someone please help me figure out why the rectangle won't show up? I am sure it's a small stupid issue but again I can't see it. Here is my code:

```
public class test2 extends Application  {
private Cell[][] cell =  new Cell[64][64];
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     GridPane pane = new GridPane(); 
     pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        for (int col = 1; col < 64; col++)
          for (int row = 1; row < 64; row++)
            pane.add(cell[col][row] = new Cell(), row, col);

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(1,3);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        VBox box2 = new VBox(rectangle);
        box2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setCenter(pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 1000, 700);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
 }
 public class Cell extends Pane{
 public Cell(){
      setStyle("-fx-border-color: white");
      setPrefSize(1000, 1000);
      return;
 }
 }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
```

Comment: You need to add the rectangle to the scene. Furthermore the side of a `Rectangle` is not provided in cells...

Comment: Should it be added to the scene or GridPane pane?

Comment: How would I dictate the size of the rectangle? I'm sure I sound slow but I'm still trying to figure this out.

@Sedrick Jefferson It should be added to the scene.

Comment: I think he is saying setPreferedWitdth and setPreferedHeight of the rectangle.